# C++ Problems with arrays, begin and end in functions

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I am trying to write a script that picks a random number and then excludes that number afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

random_device rd;   // non-deterministic generator
mt19937 gen(rd());  // to seed mersenne twister.
uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 52); // distribute results between 1 and 6 inclusive.

int testFunc(int cardArray, int cardArray2, int k) {
    cardArray[k] = dist(gen);

    copy(begin(cardArray), end(cardArray), begin(cardArray2));
    cardArray2[k] = 0;

    bool exists = find(begin(cardArray2), end(cardArray2), cardArray[k]) != end(cardArray2);

    cardArray[k] = dist(gen);

    cout << i + 1 << ": " << cardArray[k] << "    " << exists << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int cardArray[52] = { 0 };
    int cardArray2[52] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    for (int n = 0; cardArray[n] == 0 && n < 52; n++) {
    
        cardArray[i] = dist(gen);

        copy(begin(cardArray), end(cardArray), begin(cardArray2));
        cardArray2[i] = 0;

        bool exists = find(begin(cardArray2), end(cardArray2), cardArray[i]) != end(cardArray2);

        cardArray[i] = dist(gen);

        cout << i + 1 << ": " << cardArray[i] << "    " << exists << endl;
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

So there's a few problems so far. Here are the errors:

> no instance of overloaded function "end" matches the argument list
>
> no instance of overloaded function "begin" matches the argument list
>
> expression must have pointer - to - object type

I just can't figure out what's wrong. The function itself works fine if it's just in main but I need to be able to call it.

Please tell me if I need to post more information.

Comment: In the signature of `testFunc()`, `cardArray` and `cardArray2` aren't arrays, they're simple integers.

Comment: And if you try to make them arrays, they'll decay into pointers and you still can't use `begin` and `end`. Standard library containers would work better.

Comment: Well, you can make them references to arrays, then begin and end will work.

Comment: Use `std::array<int, 52>` instead.

Comment: For your problem, random shuffle allow to pick random card consecutively without taking same card twice.

Comment: Usually compiled C++ programs are not called "scripts"

Comment: All right fiddled with it and I'd like to thank you all for helping me. Yes it did work in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking in `int`s in you function not `int*`

```
int testFunc(int cardArray, int cardArray2, int k)
```

should be

```
int testFunc(int* cardArray, int* cardArray2, int k)
```

Unfortunately this will stop `std::begin` and `std::end` from working as they need an array and not a pointer.  To pass the arrays to function you need to take them by reference.  To do that we can use a template like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
int testFunc(T (&cardArray)[N], T (&cardArray2)[M], int k)
```

Or we can skip using native arrays and use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Thanks man. I'll look at the templates and the std::array and std::vector in like 30 min as I'm taking a short break. Will return with some more comments.